# What is the difference between SVG path X,Y Position and three JS X,Y position?

Tags: svg, three.js, snap.svg, svg-edit

What is difference between SVG path and Three JS X, positions?
I want place object in same place in 3d view using svg X,Y position,
How can I calculate X,Y, Z for 3D view using SVG path X,Y values?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. SVG doesn't have a z, and x,y both start from lower left corner, as opposed to svg's top left as 0,0 for drawing axis, so you would need to take that into account.

Comment: i am just asking differnce between 3Js and SVG positions?

Comment: As mentioned, in svg x,y 0,0 starts at top left http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-coordinate-system.html . In ThreeJS x,y,z starts at bottom left https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479430(v=vs.85).aspx .